# Wagtail blog example gallery image not loading

Tags: django, wagtail

I'm following the blog tutorial on the Getting Started page and I've added the BlogPageGalleryImage. I've done all the migrations and I'm able to add images to a post I created earlier as an admin.

The templates and models have all been modified as required.

However when I view the page, the image doesn't get displayed.

Below are the relevant code excerpts.

**Model.py**

```
class BlogIndexPage(Page):
    intro = RichTextField(blank=True)

    def get_context(self, request):
        # Update context to include only published posts, ordered by
        # reverse-chron
        context = super(BlogIndexPage, self).get_context(request)
        blogpages = self.get_children().live().order_by('-first_published_at')
        context['blogpages'] = blogpages
        return context

    content_panels = Page.content_panels + [
        FieldPanel('intro', classname="full")
    ]


class BlogPage(Page):
    date = models.DateField("Post date")
    intro = models.CharField(max_length=250)
    body = RichTextField(blank=True)

    search_fields = Page.search_fields + [
        index.SearchField('intro'),
        index.SearchField('body'),
    ]

    content_panels = Page.content_panels + [
        FieldPanel('date'),
        FieldPanel('intro'),
        FieldPanel('body', classname="full"),
        InlinePanel('gallery_images', label="Gallery images"),
    ]


class BlogPageGalleryImage(Orderable):
    page = ParentalKey(BlogPage, related_name='gallery_images')
    image = models.ForeignKey(
        'wagtailimages.Image', on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='+'
    )
    caption = models.CharField(blank=True, max_length=250)

    panels = [
        ImageChooserPanel('image'),
        FieldPanel('caption'),
    ]
```

**blog_page.html**

```
{% extends "base.html" %}

{% load wagtailcore_tags wagtailimages_tags %}

{% block body_class %}template-blogpage{% endblock %}

{% block content %}
<h1>{{ page.title }}</h1>
<p class="meta" >{{ page.date }}</p>

<div class="intro" >{{ page.intro }}</div>

{{ page.body|richtext }}

{% for item in page.gellery_images.all %}
<div style="float: left; margin: 10px" >
    {% image item.image fill-320x240 %}
    <p>{{ item.caption }}</p>
</div>
{% endfor %}
<p><a href="{{ page.get_parent.url }}" >Return to blog</a></p>

{% endblock %}
```

Comment: In the template, you've misspelled `gallery_images` as `gellery_images`.

Comment: @gasman thanks for spotting my error. I've spent two days on this. Oh well. Who said programming is easy. If you make this an answer I'll accept it.

Comment: @Napoleon at least check your own answer. It helps site stats.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@gasman comments ﻿﻿

> In the template, you've misspelled gallery_images as gellery_images

fixes the problem.